# What kind of temperature sensor to use?

Tags: sensor, temperature

I want to make a case for a FPGA eval board and wanted to monitor the temperature inside to start a fan if the temperature exceeds a certain value.

What kind of sensor is best suited for this task in case of simplicity and accuracy of +-1 degree celsius?

Best regards

Comment: There's probably a sensor in the FPGA itself.

Comment: Thank you. Did not think of that!

Comment: A digital temperature sensor with a serial interface would work also.  Something like the Maxim DS1620,though this is NOT meant to be a product endorsement!

Comment: Shopping questions are not allowed. ...but I personally like the DS18B20. Something analog would be cheaper, but then you really need to calibrate it if you want it to be remotely accurate. With digital you can add it to the design and not worry about it.